# RabbitMQ slow when opening a new connection

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a rather busy RabbitMQ setup which at peak times becomes extremely slow accepting new connections (RabbitMQ 3.9.14)

[image: RabbitMQ Screenshot]

I've tried fine tuning /etc/sysctl.conf as found on a guide on the RabbitMQ website

```
fs.file-max = 10000000
fs.nr_open = 10000000
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288


net.core.somaxconn = 4096
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 30
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=30
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=10
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=4

net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 10000 64000
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=1048576
```

And also played around with the rabbitmq.conf options to see if anything would have an impact, however that is unfortunately not the case

```
num_acceptors.tcp = 32
channel_max = 4096

tcp_listen_options.backlog = 512
tcp_listen_options.nodelay = true
tcp_listen_options.linger.on      = true
tcp_listen_options.linger.timeout = 0
tcp_listen_options.sndbuf = 196608
tcp_listen_options.recbuf = 196608

collect_statistics_interval = 60000
```

Due to the nature of my setup (PHP), every time messages are being published to RabbitMQ, a new connection is created, I wish I could do long-standing connections but that is beyond of what PHP is designed for

During peak activity, some connections take up to 7 seconds to open, once the connection is established however, the messages publishing performance is just fine.

I feel like I've exhausted all the logical options that I'm aware of. Is there any other tweaks that I can attempt to change in order to improve the connection performance of the node? The server load is low-ish, sitting at 15% peak. Disabling the management interface had negligible impact

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: At first, when I've updated to RabbitMQ 3.10.5, I thought that the issue was solved, however that was not the case, it just gave us a bit more headroom.

The real cause was our high churn-rate (200/s+), during my conversation in the RabbitMQ slack channel it became apparent that a high churn rate would block the event loop and cause the spikes seen above.

The solution for us was to use a proxy to re-use connections instead of opening a new one every time we publish something:
https://github.com/cloudamqp/amqproxy

This has effectively resolved our issue.

Comment: That's interesting, thank you for reporting back.